# Angular material media timeline component

Tags: angular, timeline

I am trying to build a timeline similar to "Chrome" performance tab (screenshot attached) for my webpage in Angular 1o, so I can display various waveforms on my timeline.

I don't have much experience on how to approach this, please share your feedback/suggestions that I can try and build timeline.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask